# How does Zurb Foundation detect javascript components?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I think it does it by attributes, for example in dropdown with:

```
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

With something similar but more complex:

```
if ($('div').attr('data-dropdown-menu')) {
// Create component
}
```

---

### Possible solution

One way I can think of is to have an array with the attributes of the components and the function that the component creates.
Then launch an initial process that collects all the attributes of the html, and if it matches an existing one, create the component.

---

## I want to know

I'd like to know which **function launches the process that looks for the attributes**, and if the attribute corresponds to a component, it creates the component.

---

## Initialize plugins Zurb Foundation

Thanks **Ross** I found this also looking to create my own plugin initializer.

```
  /**
   * Initialize plugins on any elements within `elem` (and `elem` itself) that aren't already initialized.
   * @param {Object} elem - jQuery object containing the element to check inside. Also checks the element itself, unless it's the `document` object.
   * @param {String|Array} plugins - A list of plugins to initialize. Leave this out to initialize everything.
   */
  reflow: function(elem, plugins) {

    // If plugins is undefined, just grab everything
    if (typeof plugins === 'undefined') {
      plugins = Object.keys(this._plugins);
    }
    // If plugins is a string, convert it to an array with one item
    else if (typeof plugins === 'string') {
      plugins = [plugins];
    }

    var _this = this;

    // Iterate through each plugin
    $.each(plugins, function(i, name) {
      // Get the current plugin
      var plugin = _this._plugins[name];

      // Localize the search to all elements inside elem, as well as elem itself, unless elem === document
      var $elem = $(elem).find('[data-'+name+']').addBack('[data-'+name+']');

      // For each plugin found, initialize it
      $elem.each(function() {
        var $el = $(this),
            opts = {};
        // Don't double-dip on plugins
        if ($el.data('zfPlugin')) {
          console.warn("Tried to initialize "+name+" on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.");
          return;
        }

        if($el.attr('data-options')){
          var thing = $el.attr('data-options').split(';').forEach(function(e, i){
            var opt = e.split(':').map(function(el){ return el.trim(); });
            if(opt[0]) opts[opt[0]] = parseValue(opt[1]);
          });
        }
        try{
          $el.data('zfPlugin', new plugin($(this), opts));
        }catch(er){
          console.error(er);
        }finally{
          return;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: I am not really familiar with zurb but this might be a good place to start: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.dropdownMenu.js

Comment: The dropdown of Zurb Foundation is an example, I'm interested in the logic behind it. I researched in his Github but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation uses plugin type approach to JS components. Each plugin is registered and initialized using registerPlugin function. Using DropDown component as an example, this call `Foundation.plugin(Dropdown, 'Dropdown');` gets the ball rolling for DropDown.

```
/**
    * @function
    * Populates the _uuids array with pointers to each individual plugin instance.
    * Adds the `zfPlugin` data-attribute to programmatically created plugins to allow use of $(selector).foundation(method) calls.
    * Also fires the initialization event for each plugin, consolidating repetitive code.
    * @param {Object} plugin - an instance of a plugin, usually `this` in context.
    * @param {String} name - the name of the plugin, passed as a camelCased string.
    * @fires Plugin#init
    */
registerPlugin: function (plugin, name) {
    var pluginName = name ? hyphenate(name) : functionName(plugin.constructor).toLowerCase();
    plugin.uuid = this.GetYoDigits(6, pluginName);

    if (!plugin.$element.attr('data-' + pluginName)) {
    plugin.$element.attr('data-' + pluginName, plugin.uuid);
    }
    if (!plugin.$element.data('zfPlugin')) {
    plugin.$element.data('zfPlugin', plugin);
    }
    /**
    * Fires when the plugin has initialized.
    * @event Plugin#init
    */
    plugin.$element.trigger('init.zf.' + pluginName);

    this._uuids.push(plugin.uuid);

    return;
}
```